# customErrors not working after deploying to Umbraco Cloud

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, umbraco7

So I'm trying to deploy to Umbraco Cloud for the first time. I have a problem where all my old pages gives me an Runtime Error, basically saying `customErrors` mode is set to RemoteOnly:

> The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons).
>   To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

If I open all 3 Web.config files I have (Web.config, Web.Release.config, and Web.Debug.config) and I add:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

It should work, right?

Alternatively I've tried something like this in **Web.config**:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Then in **Web.Production.config**:

```
<customErrors mode="On" xdt:Transform="Replace">
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/error.html" />
</customErrors>
```

I know for a fact that the above code works, as it works on my other Umbraco projects. However, I still get the Runtime Error page on live.

If I go and create a new Document Type with template, add it to contents and so on, that page works just fine and does not show the Runtime Error.

One of the problems here, I think, is that the Web.config doesn't get saved or anything. I can see that the files have updated in the KUDU manager. I have tried to restart the server a few times but it didn't help. I also run the latest 7.6.6 Umbraco.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Umbraco automatically sets the mode to `RemoteOnly` per default. It does not matter if you set the value, even in the Web.Production.config file, it will still get overwritten by Umbraco Cloud.

To change it runtime, you need to open Kudu and change the value inside Web.config to `Off`. It is not possible to do this at compile time.